# Binary to Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, image, binary, converters

I'm doing a project with Angular 8 where I need to get an image with binary format.
After my request I get a lot of data with this profil:

```
�PNG


IHDR�P�� -sBIT|d�tEXtSoftwaregnome-screenshot��> IDATx�
```

(a lot more data)
I want to display the image but I can't, I tried to use btoa() but the fonction return nothing, impossible to even do the log.

At the end after trying many things I have this

```
        let test = encodeURIComponent(result.response);
        console.log(test);
        let img = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(test);
        vm.billData.image = img;
```

The image isn't showing anyway.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: In my previous project, I had the same problem showing a pdf file which I get from server in the binary format you showed. It worked after sending "responseType:'blob'" in  request params

Comment: you're a monster thanks a lot !

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu  write it has answer, so others can benefit from this.

Comment: @SatishPai Sure will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same challenge in my previous project. I had to show a `PDF` file which i  receive from server in the binary format. It worked  After sending `responseType:'blob'` in request params